# Setting a uiimage with texture in uitableview section headers works on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

Problem:

I want to make the uitableview sections opaque with a texture background.
So I put an uiimage with a texture in the header of the sections.

Simulator:

Everything works as expected: The textured background works perfectly.

Device:

The textured background appears to be black.

I have used textured uiimages before (like in the view's background).

Does anyone has got a clue what is going on?

EDIT: See the answer to this error below in the comments.

Comment: Check the case of the image name and the actual image. They must match 100%. iOS Simulator runs on a case-insensitive file system so a file named `Image.png` can be referenced by `iMaGe.png`. The iOS Device uses a case sensitive file system, where those two names would not match.

Comment: Thank you very much @MatthiasBauch . This was the first time that this error has happened to me..

Comment: didn't know that before knowing the solution.